# Unauthorized exception with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm checking, if a given user is part of a group by this code below. I'm getting

> unauthorized exception
>   (0x80070005)

and I do not understand why? I'm using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, so why it is giving me this exception!? Anybody a hint for me? Thanks in advance!

```
public bool IsUserInGroup(SPWeb web, string groupName, string user)
{
    try
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            if (web.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>().Where(g => g.Name == groupName).Count() > 0)
            {
                SPGroup spGroup = web.Groups[groupName];
                if (spGroup.Users.OfType<SPUser>().Where(u => u.LoginName.Equals(user)).Count() > 0)
                {
                    returnValue = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = false;
            }
        });
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Classes.Logs.Error.Log_Error("IsUserInGroup", "DocumentCenterItem.cs", exp.Message, DateTime.Now);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `SP Web` inside elevated privileges. In your current implementation, you are reusing the `web` object which runs in current user context.

So, try and modify the below code as per your requirement :

```
public bool IsUserInGroup(SPWeb web, string groupName, string user)
{
    try
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {       
            using(SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            {
                using(SPWeb elevatedWeb = site.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                {
                    if (elevatedWeb.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>().Where(g => g.Name == groupName).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        SPGroup spGroup = elevatedWeb.Groups[groupName];
                        if (spGroup.Users.OfType<SPUser>().Where(u => u.LoginName.Equals(user)).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            returnValue = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            returnValue = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnValue = false;
                    }               
                }               
            }
        });
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Classes.Logs.Error.Log_Error("IsUserInGroup", "DocumentCenterItem.cs", exp.Message, DateTime.Now);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one minor comment. You should avoid `using(SPWeb elevatedWeb...)`. The web should not be disposed there. Use  `SPWeb elevatedWeb = spSite.RootWeb` instead. I recommend the SPDisposerCheck Tool from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Dispose-Checker-01da48e8